# Facebook XFBML Like Button Disappear After Unlike

Tags: facebook, button, facebook-like, xfbml

Similar to a problem I have read here, but slightly different. I have added the XFBML version of the like button to a page I am working on in a development environment. It appeared just fine to begin with. I clicked like, viewed my Facebook profile, saw that it was shared on my timeline, I then clicked 'unlike' (which I had done before using the iframe version and experienced no problems).

After clicking 'unlike', the button completely disappeared from my page. Although the markup that was generated is still present.

To make this problem even stranger, when placing the like button on a different page I do not experience the same issue. On a separate (3rd) page, I do.

I feel like this is a long shot, but any help would be greatly appreciated.

edit: said 'screw this' and decided to use AddThis for all my buttons. The facebook like button provided through AddThis also does not appear. So confused.

Answer (score 0):

Could you change the href attribute of the Facebook iframe and see if the button appears?